# How to change string in a certain tag to lowercase in multiple files

Tags: python, html-parsing, lowercase

I have the following requirement which I am trying to meet in Windows 10 using Python script:

1. Change all the filenames to lowercase in multiple folders recursively.
   For this, I used the following code:

   ```py
   import os path = "C://Users//shilpa//Desktop//content"
   for dir,subdir,listfilename in os.walk(path):
       for filename in listfilename:  
           new_filename = filename.lower()
           src = os.path.join(dir, filename) 
           dst = os.path.join(dir, new_filename) 
           os.rename(src,dst)
   ```
2. Update the references of these files embedded in certain tag. The tag here is 
   `<img href=(filename.png)>`. 
   Here, the `<img href=>` is constant and the filenames filename.png are different.

So, here is the example:

Existing filenames:

- `ABC.dita`
- `XYZ.dita`
- `IMG.PNG`

These are referenced in different files, say 
`IMG.PNG` is referenced in `XYZ.dita`.

After step1, these change as follows:

- `abc.dita`
- `xyz.dita`
- `img.png`

This will break all the references included in different files.

I want to update all the changed filename references so that the links stay intact.

I don't have any experience with Python and a beginner only. 
To achieve step2, I should be able to use regex and find a pattern, 
say,

`<img href="(this will be a link to the IMG.PNG>"`.
  This will be a part of `.dita` file.

After step1, the reference in the file will break.

How can I make changes to the filename and also retain their references? 
The ask here is, find and replace the old names by new names in all the files.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I used the following code to rename all files to lowercase recursively in multiple folders -
import os
path = "C://Users//sh001//Desktop//content"

for dir,subdir,listfilename in os.walk(path):
    for filename in listfilename:
        #i += 1
        new_filename = filename.lower()
        src = os.path.join(dir, filename) 
        dst = os.path.join(dir, new_filename.lower()) 
        os.rename(src,dst)

Comment: What are you using?  What OS/language/etc?  The appropriate tags will help direct the question to the people who are best able to answer it.  Also, you should edit your post to include the contents of your comment instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you hav e a folder containing all the relevant files.
So the problem is divided into two parts:

1. Running in a loop over the files
2. For each file lower the references

### Loopin Over The Files

This can be done using `glob` or `os.walk`.

```py
import os

upper_directory = "[insert your directory]"
for dirpath, directories, files in os.walk(upper_directory):
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
        lower_file_references(path)
```

### Lower-casing The references

When you have the path of the file, you need to read the data from it:

```
with open(path) as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Once you have the data of the referencing files, you can use this code to lower the reference string:

```
head = "<img href="
tail = ">"
img_start = s.find(head, start)
while img_start != -1:
    img_end = s.find(">", img_start)
    s = s[:img_start] +s[img_start:img_end].lower() + s[img_end:]
    img_start = img_end
```

Alternately you can use some XML parsing module. For example BeautifulSoup, this would help avoiding problems like `href=` vs `href =`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s = bs(s)
imgs = s.find_all("img")
for i in imgs:
    if "href" in i.attrs:
        i.attrs["href"] = i.attrs["href"].lower()
s = str(s)
```

In both ways you can then rewrite the files.
you can do it like that:

```
with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

### Putting it all together

```py
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def lower_file_references(file_path):
    with open(path) as f:
        s = f.read()
    s = bs(s)
    imgs = s.find_all("img")
    for i in imgs:
        if "href" in i.attrs:
            i.attrs["href"] = i.attrs["href"].lower()
    s = str(s)
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(s)

upper_directory = "[insert your directory]"
for dirpath, directories, files in os.walk(upper_directory):
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
        lower_file_references(path)
```

I must say that this is a simple method, which will work great assuming your files aren't huge. If you have big files that can't be read to memory all at once, or a lot of files you might want to think of ways avoiding reading the data of all the files.

Comment: Thank you. But, I want to do a search through all the files in multiple folders without specifically spelling out the referenced files and change all of them to lowercase.

Comment: I executed the first piece of code you had shared, it executes but the files are not changed. Used Spyder to execute. Am I missing something here?
path = "C://Users//sh001//Desktop//content"
s = """<tag1><tag2><img href="AFDDFD.ADF"></tag2><tag3><img href="SDGSFVSF.vsfv"></tag3></tag1>"""
start = 0
head = "<image href="
tail = ">"
while start != -1:
    head = "<image href="
    img_start = s.find(head, start)
    if img_start == -1:
        break
    img_end = s.find("/>", img_start)
    s = s[:img_start] +s[img_start:img_end].lower() + s[img_end:]
    start = img_end

Comment: My code sample doesn't change the file itself. You can use it once you have read the file's data, and afterward write it to the disk again.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I used your script with BeautifulSoup code. But, there is one small issue that I am sure you can help me fix. After executing the script, <html></html> gets added to all the files in multiple folders. I tried passing "lxml" in s=bs(s, "lxml"), but that doesn't seem to make any difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used "xml" instead of "lxml" and it seems to work. But, facing another problem, the script is making changes to all the image files too. Any way to add a line in script to ignore filename with extension *.png, *.jpg etc?

Comment: Yes you can add in the `glob` loop, just use `endswith`

Comment: Could you please share the code for glob that selects only *.xml, *.dita files? I tried but couldn't make it work in the beautifulsoup code that you have provided.

Comment: glob loop did not work since I was using Python 27. I installed Python 37 and it seems to work now. Code for this is - 
import glob
for files in glob.iglob('directorypath/**/*.xml', recursive=True):
And, in the code you provided, I had to make following change -
path=os.path.join(dirpath, files) #here, I had to change fname to files

Comment: You can't replace `walk` with `glob` and not adjust your code, these are two different functions both are useful for search in file names but they are not the same function.

Comment: to use ends with write `if path.endswith("png"): continue`